# change the render frequency in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, render

I have a question that is possible to change the frequency the render method. I found this:

> By default in libgdx, the rendering thread calls the render() method of your ApplicationListener class continuously, with a frequency that depends on your hardware (30-50-80 times per second). 
>   I use

```
Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(false);
```

in my create method, rendering is stoping and starting if user touch the screen. But I want to slow freqency for example 1 time per second. Is it possible to solve this issue or I can only use default settings of render method. I searched but didnt find the solution. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep,use this to stop the continuos rendering.

```
Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(false);
```

Then you can just call the render method every second. Use Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() to know if a second have passed since the last render.

Edit: thanks to P.T. comment: this is how you call the render:

```
Gdx.graphics.requestRendering();
```

Comment: Invoke `Gdx.graphics.requestRendering()` to kick the renderer.  See 
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Continuous-%26-non-continuous-rendering for details on when its kicked automatically.